# show why a post was off-topic in close-vote reviewing

Tags: feature-request, review, vote-to-close, off-topic

I notice that when I review a post in the close-vote review queue that has been voted as off-topic, I only see at the top that the post was off-topic. I have no idea of finding out why it is off-topic unless I click "close", then select "off-topic" as the reason, then see which reasons have the blue marker that indicates other people voted like that. So I requested that instead of a generic message like "This question is off-topic", to see a message such as "Questions require valid code to reproduce the problem".

Answer (score 1):

I believe you should be reading the question and deciding why **you** believe the question should be closed before clicking the "Close" link, without taking into consideration with what other people think.

To show why a question is up for closure on the page would likely cause people to see it and just vote on the same thing because "everyone else is doing it." To close a question, each person who reviews it should be thinking critically about why the question needs work, why it doesn't fit our Q&A format, or why it is just plain bad. Or better yet, helping to improve it with comments!

Regardless, 5 close votes of any type closes it, so your reasoning doesn't need to match everyone else's if you do decide it is worth closing.

Comment: I generally try to make up my mind on my own before I vote to close.  But once I've done that, I do take into consideration how others have voted.  I do agree, however, that this information does not need to be displayed in the review queue directly.

Comment: Exactly, if it's displayed, then it's easy to just follow the flock. It's still available, you just have to click for it. I believe that deterrent is sufficient.